# How many megapixels are needed on a smartphone to take above quality photos?

Tags: image-quality, megapixels, cameraphones

Just regular above quality photos for Facebook and normal things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Facebook images are usually displayed at around 720×540 pixels. That is about **one third of a megapixel**, so for that use, *anything* you can buy is overkill *in terms of megapixels*. This is perfectly fine for almost all online display, and will even make decent small-sized prints.

However, megapixels do not accurately represent image quality. The answers to [Why do some DSLRs have fewer megapixels than some pocket cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/why-do-some-dslrs-have-fewer-megapixels-than-some-pocket-cameras) provide some of the explanation as to why. You can't really use that as a way to make your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the smartphone market I would say any phone with 5Mpx can be a good choice. (For example the old Xperia X10 mini does pretty good photos for its price).
But smartphone cameras are always a huge compromise work and as said Mpx never tell so much of the story. So maybe it is better to chose two or three models and compare them here http://www.gsmarena.com/piccmp.php3